# Is there a way to automatically search for conditions as I add them in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I am not sure if I will explain this properly but basically, I have this formula:

```
=hyperlink($P$2&ifs(F4="SYSxx",$P$3,F4="SYS39",$P$5)&"&range=A"&match(A4,indirect("'"&F4&"'!A:A"),0),"Cell")
```

Its function is to look through various sheets for a match and then to create a link to that cell. Another example:

```
=ifs(iserror(match(A3,SYSxx!A:A,0))=FALSE,"SYSxx",iserror(match(A3,'SYS39'!A:A,0))=FALSE,"SYS39")
```

This one looks through a work order sheet to find a match and then determines which system it originates from. I don't want go through each formula and adjust it each time I add a new system sheet. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Update: So for the first one I just did a vlookup with a named ranged and I think that will tidy it up nicely, but the second formula is what everything relies on. Here is a copy of the sheet with the cells in black background with white text the ones being affected.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11wAXuPcoXmuUU26mEhINFZAdVZ8Tg6PxhdoQVXuyfh8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Share a copy of your sheet & show which part you edit manually

Answer (score 0):

I may have an answer that works for you, or at least a starting point.
My apologies for not formatting this answer, or the sheet, very well - I'll correct that tomorrow; it's too late tonight.

I replaced your formula in F3 with the following:
=ArrayFormula(ifs(iserror(VLOOKUP(A3:A,indirect($R$3),1,0))=FALSE,"SYSxx",iserror(VLOOKUP(A3:A,indirect($R$4),1,0))=FALSE,"SYS38",iserror(VLOOKUP(A3:A,indirect($R$5),1,0))=FALSE,"SYS39"))

See cell G3 in my sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15jwB-YX1OeCz1jD4Rv816qXFImX-IWQo8ILLoh4Nf0o/edit?usp=sharing

Note also that when you add a new sheet name in column P, the indirect reference in column R must match. 
The formula in G3 needs some expansion to ensure it captures every possible sheet it needs to search, but this is easily done, by adding more clauses to the IFS statement, to check more cells below R5.

Does this seem useful?

Comment: Thanks for the response, my main goal was to mostly remove the need to add clauses every time I add a sheet. I was hoping that gsheets had some sort of lookup table thing that I didn't know about. The more I look into, the more it seems I just have to make a script or something.